# Insert GetMetaData ChildItems.name directly into a table without using any iterators -Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a method available in azure data factory to directly insert the getmetadata activity childitems directly into a sql table without using any control activities?

Any help would be appreciated.

regards,
Sandeep

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this directly, but you could convert the output.childItems array to a string and pass it to a Stored Procedure for further processing. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Hi @Joel Cochran, I have 1000  of files to process and all the file names are extracted using Get Metadata activity and then loaded into a table using stored procedure activity used inside a for each activity. Insertion of the filenames into the table consumes a lot of time and it slows down the pipeline entirely. So we are planning to insert all GetMetadata activity childitems in a single execution to once table and then manipulate it using stored procedure. That may improve the performance of the pipeline.

Comment: I can't think of a faster way within the confines of ADF to perform this task as you have described it. An Azure Function or Azure Batch activity may be better suited to this scenario.

Comment: I'd follow Joel's suggestion to pass the childitems to an sp which separates and writes them into a table.  However I'm wondering why you want a list of filenames in a table?  If you're going to then process those files one by one within adf you may not need to store the filenames in a table first.

Comment: Hi Jason, We need to sort the files based on the filenames and process, that's why we need to store it in a table.